# Links getting corrupted in HTML emails

Tags: html, email, encoding, hyperlink, href

I am sending an email with a HTML link embedded as follows:

```
<a href="https://mydomain.com/?d=zJBTDhP%2bZxolUHQ6qJ2yFA%3d%3d" target='_blank'>Link</a>
```

When called the query string parameter 'd' is URL decoded and then decrypted (Rijndael) using our own function. Very occasionally (1% of cases), with certain users this fails and the error log shows that the query string value has morphed into this:

```
mWOGQuC%2oMkbyHUD6dW2lSN%3q%3q
```

so from:

```
zJBTDhP%2bZxolUHQ6qJ2yFA%3d%3d
```

to:

```
mWOGQuC%2oMkbyHUD6dW2lSN%3q%3q
```

Due to the intermittent nature of this problem...is this likely to be an overzealous spam filter or is this an encoding problem on our side?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am having a very similar issue and wondering if you ever resolved this.

Comment: I never found a conclusive answer, but in the end I switched to GUIDs and have not seen that problem since. Do your links have encoded = characters (%3d)? I suspected these were the cause but can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Yes my links contain some url encoded characters and very occasionally, the encoding gets corrupted somehow rendering the links unusable. Tough to reproduce and debug